# Integer value of x?

Tags: integration, definition, integers

I got a problem this evening which I might well be able to solve, but am unable to confidently interpret the information it has given me. It goes as follows:

If $n\in\Bbb{N}$ and **$[x]$ is the integer value of $x$**, show that

$$\int_0^n[2^{x}]dx=n2^n-log_2((2^n)!)$$

I have emboldened the bit that I don't understand. Does it only want me to take integer values for $x$, i.e: what would the graph of $y=[2^x]$ look like?

Comment: Say $x = 2$, then $2^2 = 4$ and $[2^2] = [4] = 4$. On the other hand for $x = 2.1$ then $[2^{2.1}] = [4.287..] = 4$. So take all values of $x$, but you have to "truncate" the value of the function and take only the integer values

Comment: If $f(x)=\lfloor 2^x \rfloor$ then $f(x)=1$ for $0≤x<1$, $f(x)=2$ for $1≤x<\log_2 2$ and so on.

Comment: Ok, thanks that pretty much answers it!

Comment: If $x$ is any real number, then $[x]$ means the _integral part_ of $x$, i.e. $x$ rounded down to the nearest whole number. (I have never seen the term _integer value_ before.) So for instance $[\pi]=3, \sqrt 2 = 1, [42]=42$ etc. For completeness: if $x$ is negative, then "rounded down" means "rounded towards $-\infty$", so e.g. $[-2.5]=-3$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation means $[x]$ is the least integer not greater than $x$.  Thus $[2.9] = 2$ and $[-2.9] = -3$ and $[3.0] = 3$.

This is a bit old fashioned; modern practice is to call this the "floor" function 
$\lfloor x \rfloor$.

So $[2^x]$ is $1$ until $x=1$, then $2$ until $x=\log_2 3$, then $3$ until 
$x=\log_2 4 = 2$ and so forth.

The integral becomes a discrete sum; don't forget that the domains of $x$ in which the integrand takes on each successive integer are not all the same length.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{n}\left \lfloor 2^x \right \rfloor = \sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}{k\cdot( log_2(k+1)-log_2(k))}=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}{k\cdot( \frac{\ln(k+1)}{\ln2}-\frac{\ln(k)}{\ln2})}=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}{k\cdot( \frac{\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)}{\ln2})}=\frac{1}{\ln2}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}{k\cdot(\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)})=\frac{1}{\ln2}\cdot\sum_{S=1}^{2^n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{S}{(-\ln(k)+\ln({k+1}))}=\frac{1}{\ln2}\sum_{S=1}^{2^n-1}{\ln(S+1)}=\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}{\log_{2}(i))}=\log_{2}(2^n!)$$